# Using switch statement for golf scenario

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement

Beginner here trying to return a comment method:

```
public static String comment(int score, int parForHole) {
    if (parForHole - score > 4)
        return "condor!!!!";
    if (parForHole - score == 3)
        return "albatross!!!";
    if (parForHole - score == 2)
        return "eagle!!";
    if (parForHole - score == 1)
        return "birdie!";
    if (parForHole - score == 0)
        return "par";
    if (parForHole - score == -1)
        return "bogey";
    if (parForHole - score == -2)
        return "double bogey";
    if (parForHole - score < -2)
        return "triple+ bogey";

    return "asdasd"; // Replace by a suitable switch stmt.
}
```

Is there a similar way to do this using the switch statement? I am not too familiar with it.
Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate a total of parForHole - score and then run the result through a switch statement.

```
public static String comment(int score, int parForHole) {
    int total = parForHole - score;

    switch(total) {

        case 3 :
            return "albatross!!!";


        //   ... and so on


    }

    if (total > 4)
        return "condor!!!!";
    if (total <= 3)
       return "triple+ bogey!!!!";

    return "asdasd";
}
```

but for the comparisons > 4 etc. I guess you have to keep the if Statements.

Comment: break after return? really?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String comment(int score, int parForHole) {
    String strig;
    switch(parForHole - score){
        case 1:
            string = "something";
            break;
        case 2:
            string = "something else";
            break;
        default:
            string = "default string";
            break;
    }
    return string;
}
```

Switch is just basicly switching to the case what you give it. If parForHole - score is 1 it will switch to case 1. If parForHole - score gives an undefined value switch will use the default case.